# Upgraded to 64bit Office and Java. Cannot connect to Access Database

Tags: java, database, ms-access

I had a working Java application that connected to a Access database. My old machine was 32bit Windows with JRE7 (32 bit).

I upgraded to a 64BIT Windows with JRE8 (64 bit).

The application asks for the specific location of the Java Executible Folder, which I provide as

```
 C:\Program Files\Java\JRE8\bin. 
 OR
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin
```

When running the application I get the error

```
 java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name 
 not found and no default driver specified
 Failed to connect to Access DB: Main
```

I have tried pointing the application to the old version of Java as well as the new. I also confirmed I have MS Access Drivers both 32 and 64 bit. When I type java -version it pulls java version "1.8.0_171" which is in the 32 bit folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Java

Here is my connection string.

```
 private static Connection getAccessDBConnection()
{
        Connection dbConnection = null;
        String ACCESSDB_Driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
        String connURL="jdbc:odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + databasePath.trim() + "\\" + accessFileName.trim() + ".accdb;";

        try 
        {
            Class.forName(ACCESSDB_Driver);
            dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL, "","");
        }
        catch (Exception err) 
        {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }

        return dbConnection;
}
```

Any advice on what to check? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you forced use of the x64 jre already ?

Comment: @Marged Since posting the question, I have uninstalled/deleted the 32bit version of Java. Can you explain what you mean by "forced use of x64"? Now when I do java -version I am seeing the 64bit version. When I point the application I enter the 64bit path,  C:\Program Files\Java\JRE8\bin

Comment: @Marged Is there any possibility old registry keys are to blame?